Run a PCJ application in a Slurm environment
I'm trying to run a PCJ (https://pcj.icm.edu.pl/) based app (parallel computing in Java) in a cluster environment where the installed resource manager is Slurm.
I'm getting confused about how to match both (sbatch input file, srun arguments, Java code, ...).
The catch is that PCJ starts tasks by itself on the slave nodes and may conflict Slurm launch process.
Ideally, I would like a basic working example.
Thanks !
For 2 slave nodes, I run sbatch on this file on the "master" host :
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 2                     # Number of nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node 1      # Number of tasks per node
#SBATCH --time=00:10:00          # Required time

srun -l java -jar test-pcj-slurm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Java code :
public class PcjSlurm implements StartPoint
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
         String[] nodes = getStepNodes();
        System.out.println( "node name " + getNodeName() );
        if ( getNodeName().equals( "slave2" ) )
        {
            PCJ.executionBuilder( PcjSlurm.class ).addNodes( nodes ).start();
        }
        else
            System.out.println( "slave job" );
    }

    private static String[] getStepNodes() // returns ["slave1", "slave2"]
    {
        return System.getenv( "SLURM_STEP_NODELIST" ).split( "," );
    }

    private static String getNodeName()
    {
        return System.getenv( "SLURMD_NODENAME" );
    }

    // StartPoint interface

    @Override
    public void main() throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println( "PCJ id " + PCJ.myId() );
    }
}

I get this output (slurm-XXX.out) :
1: node name slave1
1: slave job
0: node name slave2
0: avr. 03, 2024 10:08:36 AM org.pcj.internal.InternalPCJ start
0: INFOS: PCJ version UNKNOWN

Oddly, the code in the StartPoint.main() implementation does not seem to be executed.

You should also have an err file. Is it throwing an exception and exiting?

No I don't get an err file nor exception.

@matt
By default slurm merges standard and error outputs. I verified this by adding "-e slurm-%A.err" to sbatch command line, getting the last 2 lines (0: avr..., 0: INFOS...) in the error file and the first 3 lines in the standard output file.

It seems like, since you have a slurm node, your nodes.txt could just have 'localhost' or some such. That way it will treat it like a single computer. You're using "slave1" and "slave2"? I don't know how that relates to their examples. Although the javadocs are a bit tough to find.

I tried running the app outiside Slurm context and I already get problems, so I should start by fixing this.

The so-called "controller/worker" (aka "master/slave") model is not the best to be used inside Slurm--nonetheless, there is a way to run that.
Have a look at the "srun" man page under "MULTIPLE PROGRAM CONFIGURATION". Here you can refer srun --multi-prog to a config file you have to supply, where the controller part and several worker parts need to be configured.
It will cause srun to first run the controller part, followed by (the configured amount of) worker parts, possibly distributed over several nodes.
Unfortunately, one of the disadvantages is then the "how your controller and worker find their (network) way to each other" question. This is beyond the scope of srun and needs to be parametrized within your application.
In case that does not work this way, you can make use of srun's feature to write out a host file containing the currently allocated nodes.
Assuming your java program accepts "-n ##" as number of processes/slaves to start, and "--hostfile=" as the file name of participating nodes, you could use:
#!/usr/bin/bash
#SBATCH -n 24

srun hostname > hostfile.$SLURM_JOB_ID
/path/to/your/JavaProgram -n $SLURM_NPROCS  --hostfile=hostfile.$SLURM_JOB_ID 


2 fixes : use deploy() instead of start() (ExecutionBuilder) and do not add localhost to host file when multiple slave nodes are targeted.
